# Fixed navbar will not work on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fixed, navbar

I've got a problem in getting menu being fixed on Mobile(small screen) view. I've tried working around this several hours, and tried all the common  tricks (position:fixed etc). Even the standard twitter-bootstrap template for a fixed navbar: (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) is not fixed.

Is the position:fixed support dropped on mobile?

**Edit:** The jquery mobile fixed navbars are working, but neither of the ordinary solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code sample.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the code sample used in the example sites hosted on bootstrap - but that does not give a fixed toolbar on Android. Thank you for your answer though.